# I was writing a code to enter a number and then reversing it, but the modulo isn't working it seems. What could have gone wrong here?

Tags: java, modulo

My concern is only with why the modulo (%) isn't working. Please don't comment on the code on it's entirety. My code is as displayed below.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        
        
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        int num = scanner.nextInt();
        
        int count = 0;
        while(num!=0) {
        num = num/10;
        count++;
        }
        System.out.println("Total digits = " + count );
        
        
        int rem = num % 10;
        System.out.println(rem);
        
        
        
        
    }}
```

The output is

[image]

Also quick note: the output for "rem" is 0 only when "num" is passed as an operand. If a number replaces the "num" then the code works just fine

Comment: because 0 % 10 equals 0. So it's working as intended

Comment: but i did specify value for num in line10. >int num = scanner.nextInt();

Comment: but then you are modifying it inside your while loop

Comment: ohh it changes outside of a loop too? how do I fix it?

Comment: I specified a new variable which is equal to "num" and it does the job now. Thankyou so much

Answer (score 0):

There is a wrong logic used for reversing the number. You can try below code.

```
 public class ReverseNumberExample1   
    {  
      public static void main(String[] args)   
      {  
       int number = 987654, reverse = 0;  
       while(number != 0)   
       {  
         int remainder = number % 10;  
         reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;  
         number = number/10;  
       }  
       System.out.println("The reverse of the given number is: " + reverse);  
     }  
    }
```

Comment: please don't just post copy-paste ready solutions. At the very least provide explanation of what you did

Comment: He is using wrong logic in reversing number. So, i just gave him right logic for that from https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-reverse-a-number-in-java

Comment: you gave him code to copy-paste

Comment: Okay, I will give explanation next time.